# Unable to see the device list when running the adb devices on cmd

Tags: appium, appium-android

getting below exception when opened the genymotion emulator.

**Note :** Set the path of sdk in genymotion. and adb version is also latest.and also unable to kill the process adb on task manager. three adb processes are running.

adb server is out of date. killing...

```
cannot bind 'tcp:5037' ADB server didn't ACK 
*failed to start daemon* error:
```

Comment: did you try "adb kill-server" command?

Comment: Yes tried adb kill-server after that again trying to start server or trying adb devices. getting the same.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do following task :

1) Open genymotion settings

2) Specify sdk path for the adb manually

3) adb kill-server

4) adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

Solution was if we are running command prompt by admin rights, then it is working fine,Thanks for your valuable inputs.